# How to get the user's country for a HTTP request in the Backend?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, backend

I am trying to get the country where the user is sending the request to my server.

So far I have found those solutions:

`https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip`

`https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java`

These solutions are using MaxMind database GeoIP2 Country Database which has a license and for this specific project I have restriction with Libraries (legal aspects because of the business)

I have found some topics mentioning that Google API can provide this service, but that doesn't interest me as I want a solution that I can host myself and it is implemented using Java or Kotlin.

Does someone know a solution different from the one mentioned (that runs on the backend)?

Comment: Please remove all given tags, as none of the technologies you tagged is part of the question or the answers. Also, the tag `backend` should be reconsidered, as it adds no value to the selection criteria.

Comment: I don't agree with you as I am looking for support in the specific technologies tagged. Answers using any other technologies (e.g Python) are not interesting for me at all.

Comment: As far as your description goes, the type of technology you look for is not dependent on the implementation in any language. Neither geoip nor google's API are restricted to the usage of any client language. So a good answer can serve a way broader audience ;).

Comment: My question actually points that both services that you used as example are not suitable for me (to exactly avoid people recommending it). As I mentioned before the question describes exactly what I need (advices/solutions using kotlin/java).

Answer (score 1):

I've coded a little service that returns the country based on data I've acquired from http://ipverse.net/

It should be license free but correct me if I am wrong. According to the website the data is provided by the five big RIRs.

The website updates its data ~5am. The Cron job that updates the IP Blocks is scheduled at 6am. The data should be accurate I guess.

*edit
I've replicated the algo and created a github action to keep it updated, check it out: https://github.com/jaecktec/ncc-inetnum-parser

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if, from an architecture point of view, this is a good solution, but you could install a command line tool in your backend server and use that.

For example: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/geoiplookup.1.html

There are also some free web API you could use, have a look [here](https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis#geocoding)

Comment: That drills down to the maxmind database again... :/ check comments